# Visual Studio client HTML Intellisense for WebForms server controls

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, intellisense

I want the same HTML Intellisense as for `<a runat="server"></a>` to also display for `<asp:HyperLink runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>` as well (client events, attributes, etc).

I already tried creating and adding this file to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html":

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/html5/asp'
            xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
            targetNamespace='http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/html5/asp'
            xmlns:vs='http://schemas.microsoft.com/Visual-Studio-Intellisense'
            xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            vs:clientom="w3c-dom1.tlb"
            vs:ishtmlschema="true"
            vs:isserverschema="false"
            vs:htmlflavor="5.0"
            vs:cssschema="CSS 2.1"
            vs:SuccinctFriendlyName="ASP HTML5"
            vs:customattrprefix="data-">

    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            Microsoft Visual Studio schema for ASP HTML5
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>

    <xsd:include schemaLocation="CommonHTML5Types.xsd" />

    <xsd:attributeGroup name="coreAttributeGroup">
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="commonHTML5coreAttributeGroup" />
        <xsd:attribute name="contenteditable" vs:standalone="noname">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:NMTOKEN">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="true" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="false" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="inherit" />
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:attribute>
        <xsd:attribute name="draggable" vs:standalone="noname">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:NMTOKEN">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="true" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="false" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="auto" />
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:attribute>
        <xsd:attribute name="spellcheck" vs:standalone="noname">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:NMTOKEN">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="true" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="false" />
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:attribute>
    </xsd:attributeGroup>

    <xsd:attributeGroup name="ariaAttributeGroup">
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="commonHTML5ariaAttributeGroup" />
        <xsd:attribute name="aria-invalid" default="false" vs:category="WAI-ARIA">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:NMTOKEN">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="grammar" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="false" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="spelling" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="true" />
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:attribute>
    </xsd:attributeGroup>

    <xsd:attributeGroup name="commonEventsGroup">
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="commonHTML5commonEventsGroup" />
    </xsd:attributeGroup>

    <xsd:attributeGroup name="commonAttributeGroup">
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="coreAttributeGroup" />
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="microdataAttributeGroup" />
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="ariaAttributeGroup" />
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="commonEventsGroup" />
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="coreServerAttributeGroup" />
    </xsd:attributeGroup>

  <xsd:group name="flowContent">
    <xsd:choice>
      <xsd:element ref="HyperLink" />
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:group>

  <xsd:group name="phrasingContent">
    <xsd:choice>
      <xsd:element ref="HyperLink" />
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:group>

  <xsd:group name="interactiveContent">
    <xsd:choice>
      <xsd:element ref="HyperLink" />
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:group>

  <xsd:element name="HyperLink" vs:disallowedancestor="HyperLink" vs:contentmodel="transparent">
    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
      <xsd:attributeGroup ref="commonAttributeGroup" />
      <xsd:attributeGroup ref="aServerAttributeGroup" />
      <xsd:attribute name="href" type="xsd:anyURI" vs:preferredextensions=".asp;.aspx;.cshtml;.vbhtml;.asmx;.asax;.ashx;.asix;.ascx;.htm;.html;.xml;.xsd;.config;.asa;.css;.shtm;.shtml;.php;.jsp" />
      <xsd:attribute name="target" type="browsingContext" vs:requiredattribute="href" />
      <xsd:attribute name="name" />
      <xsd:attribute name="ping" vs:requiredattribute="href" />
      <xsd:attribute name="rel" type="anchorLinkType" vs:requiredattribute="href" />
      <xsd:attribute name="media" type="mediaType" default="screen" vs:requiredattribute="href" />
      <xsd:attribute name="hreflang" type="i18LanguageCode" vs:requiredattribute="href" />
      <xsd:attribute name="type" type="simpleContentType" vs:requiredattribute="href" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

And adding `xmlns:asp='http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/html5/asp'` to the `<body></body>` tag, but I only get the usual server side only Intellisense.

I actually want this for my custom server controls, but can get there on my own from here.

Comment: You might need to add `ASPxScriptIntelliSense.js` to  your project to work. Have a look http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument8122

Comment: @Nadeem - no, that is only for JavaScript (not server controls)